# ArrayList<String> to CharSequence[]

Tags: java, arraylist, charsequence

What would be the easiest way to make a `CharSequence[]` out of `ArrayList<String>`?

Sure I could iterate through every `ArrayList` item and copy to `CharSequence` array, but maybe there is better/faster way?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

You can use [`List#toArray(T[])`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T[]%29) for this.

```
CharSequence[] cs = list.toArray(new CharSequence[list.size()]);
```

Here's a little demo:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "waa");
CharSequence[] cs = list.toArray(new CharSequence[list.size()]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cs)); // [foo, bar, waa]
```

Comment: +1 - The point is that `CharSequence` is an interface and `String` implements it.

Answer (score 18):

Given that type `String` already implements `CharSequence`, this conversion is as simple as asking the list to copy itself into a fresh array, which won't actually copy any of the underlying character data. You're just copying references to `String` instances around:

```
final CharSequence[] chars = list.toArray(new CharSequence[list.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is 12 years old but I could not find a solution for this in Kotlin. Eventually I figured it out:

**Kotlin:**

```kotlin
val listOfStrings: List<String> = listOf("Hello,", "World!")
val charSequenceArray: Array<CharSequence> = listOfStrings.toArray(arrayOf<CharSequence>()) //Equivalent type to `CharSequence[]`
```