# Converting ArrayList<T> to CharSequence[]

Tags: android, arrays, object, charsequence

I want to convert my ArrayList containing elements with the toString method shadowed in "T":

```
public String toString(){
    return name + "  " + realname;
}
```

to a CharSequence array containing all the "T"s toString. Checked some stuff out but nothing works for me since CharSequence[] can't be concatenated (correct me if i'm wrong).

Saw a solution for the ArrayList at -> [ArrayList<String> to CharSequence[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032342/arrayliststring-to-charsequence) which didn't work out for me

I'm doing this because I've searched for devices ("T") and added them to a Arraylist, the user then has to make a choice which one to accept by clicking on a mutliple choice dialogwindow as shown under **DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY** in [this link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlertDialogSamples.html)

Please help me out cause it's driving me mad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So through the responses via the comments you guys suggested a solution with subsequence. However **[this is a similar solution](http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/java-how-to-convert-string-into-array/)** I guess and it's semi-implemented in my code already so I'm gonna go with this one with a few modifications ofcourse.

Feel free to still give feedback if it's a bad way to implement or if there actually exists other ways of doing it!

::EDIT::

The solution was the following: I tried ot the code given by the link and take note that my ArrayList.toString() returns a String object with the following look for each element in the List

> "[foo, bar, super, duper]"

Taken to account that **the toString() is overriden** in the my object class. The following is done

```
    private String[] stringToArray(String str){
    str = str.substring(1, str.length()-1);
    String[] str2array = str.split(", ");

    return str2array;
}
```

And voila I have the String[] array and can now represent them as choices in my single choice list.